# What is Jigdo and how is it done?

Tags: jigdo

I happen to see that it is possible to update the Ubuntu image in daily basis. But I don't have the faintest idea on how it is done. Please explain the limits and possibilities in using Jigdo in simple terms.

Comment: I think this would answer most of our questions http://www.tldp.org/HOWTO/Debian-Jigdo/howjigdoworks.html

Comment: @Braiam someone flagged the question as 'Unclear'. Can you please edit the question if you understood what I meant ?

Comment: I actually don't know why was voted to close as unclear...